# Spotify briefly stealing focus?

Tags: windows-10, spotify

This issue is driving me crazy. Spotify (or a process related to Spotify) keeps stealing focus for a split second from whatever program I am in then quickly snaps focus back to that program. This completely screws up my typing and is extremely annoying. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling and it sometimes helps for a bit but the issue always returns. As soon as I close Spotify the problem goes away. Anyone know a possible fix for this issue? I am on Windows 10.

Comment: I'd consider asking on Spotify support forum first. They do handle technical problems well (from my experience).